# create mysql user to connect from PHP

Tags: mysql, nginx, centos, php

```
CREATE USER 'newuser'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON * . * TO 'newuser'@'localhost' WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

But when I try to connect from PHP:

```
mysql_connect("localhost", "newuser", "password");
```

for newuser i get:

```
Access denied for user 'newuser'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

but root connect succesfully.

Why can't 'newuser' connect?

Its strange, but while mysql_connect show error, with PDO i can successfully connect.
Maybe PHP Version 5.4.13 has some problem with mysql_connect function.

**SOLVED:** developer use mysql_connect("127.0.0.1", "newuser", "evtevtetv$q"); and php recognize evtevtetv**$q** as variable.

Comment: You may have to use 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost? (if you're programming in Windows?)

Comment: You shouldn't need that when you use CREATE USER but, can you try to run "FLUSH PRIVILEGES;" with your mysql client.

Comment: Are you able to connect with newuser through MySQL console?

Comment: Are you connecting from localhost itself? Or from different machine

Answer (score 1):

what if you try this?

```
CREATE USER 'newuser';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON * . * TO 'newuser'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'password' WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
CREATE USER 'newuser'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON * . * TO 'newuser'@'localhost' WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

WITH GRANT OPTION means that the user to whom you are granting the privilege can grant it further..

We never use it with create user command

Comment: see this http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/grant.html

Answer (score 1):

1. Can you connect through the command line? Like so

   ```
   mysql -u newuser -p
   ```

   If you can then it might be a problem with your PHP.
2. Sometimes you need to restart MySQL in order for the changes to take effect.
3. Like Alexey said, try removing the `@'localhost'` from the query to create the username as this might be causing a problem.
4. You should also make sure that the user is actually being created by logging in to MySQL as root (`mysql -u root -p`) and seeing if the user exists with `SELECT * FROM mysql.user;` and see if the username exists and if the permissions are correct.